# Finding all possible readings of a mechanical odometer with variable wheels

Tags: haskell

The problem can be described as finding all possible readings of a mechanical odometer, with the caveat that its wheels may have varying number of digits.

```
odometer = [["a1","a2","a3"],["b1","b2"],["c1","c2","c3","c4"]]
```

What I've got so far:

```
read_heads :: [[[Char]]] -> [[Char]]
read_heads [[[]]] = [[]]
read_heads x = map head x

-- pushes the first element of a list to the end
rotate :: [a] -> [a]
rotate [] = []
rotate (x:xs) = xs ++ [x]
```

http://www.cartell.ie/car_check/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/Odometer-1.jpg

Edit: clarifying the question. Given the odometer above, create a list that contains all its possible readings.

```
["a1","b1","c1"]
["a1","b1","c2"]
["a1","b1","c3"]
["a1","b1","c4"]
["a1","b2","c1"]
["a1","b2","c2"]
["a1","b2","c3"]
["a1","b2","c4"]
etc.
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably the easiest one:

```
Prelude> let odometer a = sequence a
Prelude> odometer [["a1","a2","a3"],["b1","b2"],["c1","c2","c3","c4"]]
[["a1","b1","c1"],["a1","b1","c2"],["a1","b1","c3"],["a1","b1","c4"],["a1","b2","c1"],
["a1","b2","c2"],["a1","b2","c3"],["a1","b2","c4"],["a2","b1","c1"],["a2","b1","c2"],
["a2","b1","c3"],["a2","b1","c4"],["a2","b2","c1"],["a2","b2","c2"],["a2","b2","c3"],
["a2","b2","c4"],["a3","b1","c1"],["a3","b1","c2"],["a3","b1","c3"],["a3","b1","c4"],
["a3","b2","c1"],["a3","b2","c2"],["a3","b2","c3"],["a3","b2","c4"]]
Prelude>
```

`sequence` is a function that deals with monads. If you want to use Haskell, you need to understand monads, so might just as well start now.

If you are not ready to let the mighty monad into your life yet, here's a more mundane version:

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| let odometer (xs:yys) = [x:ys | x<-xs, ys<-odometer yys]
Prelude|     odometer [] = [[]]
Prelude| :}
Prelude> odometer [["a1","a2","a3"],["b1","b2"],["c1","c2","c3","c4"]]
[["a1","b1","c1"],["a1","b1","c2"],["a1","b1","c3"],["a1","b1","c4"],["a1","b2","c1"],
["a1","b2","c2"],["a1","b2","c3"],["a1","b2","c4"],["a2","b1","c1"],["a2","b1","c2"],
["a2","b1","c3"],["a2","b1","c4"],["a2","b2","c1"],["a2","b2","c2"],["a2","b2","c3"],
["a2","b2","c4"],["a3","b1","c1"],["a3","b1","c2"],["a3","b1","c3"],["a3","b1","c4"],
["a3","b2","c1"],["a3","b2","c2"],["a3","b2","c3"],["a3","b2","c4"]]
Prelude>
```

It does exactly what it says on the tin:

- Given a list of odometer wheels `(xs:yys)`
- the list of all possible readings is the list of all possible combinations of *x* and *ys* `= [ x:ys`
- such that `|`
- *x* is taken from the list of all possible positions of the first wheel `x<-xs`
- and `,`
- *ys* is taken from the list of all possible readings of an odometer constructed from the rest of the wheels (that is, all besides the first)  `ys<-odometer yys]`.
- If the odometer has no wheels `[]`
- there's just one possible reading, which is empty `= [[]]`